# Is it possible to have task-dependent SBT dependencies?

Tags: sbt

We have custom SBT task which has a dependency (`addSbtPlugin`). But this plugin is not actually used for compilation and testing, though SBT tries to resolve dependency immediately.

Is is possible to make SBT resolve this dependency only when the particular task is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible. If I understood you correctly, what you are asking is similar to "is it possible to resolve a library dependency only when I run the code that depends on it?". If your task depends on the plugin (or is introduced by it), that dependency has to be resolved when the project is loading.

On another note, if this plugin is not related to the project itself and you don't want to force other maintainers to use it, it's a good idea to add it to your [global config](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Using-Plugins.html#Global+plugins) (which will affect only you and work for all sbt projects on your computer):

- place `addSbtPlugin` in `~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/`
- if that plugin needs any settings, you can add them to `~/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt`

(substitute the version, if you are using older sbt)